# list cannot change inside ValueEventListener

Tags: android, list, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to put data from firebase database in a list, however I get the error : "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0", I even tried to add to the list manually inside the valueEventListener as shown in  the comment, but still it's empty

this is my code :

```
public class Playing extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static List<Question> list_question=new ArrayList<>();
Question currentQuestion;
int index=0; 


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_playing);
    final DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("quiz");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            /* 

            Question question=new Question();
            question.setQuestion("eeee");
            question.setAnswerA("zzzzz");
            question.setAnswerB("aazss");
            question.setAnswerC("ytyty");
            question.setAnswerD("jkjkjkjk");
            question.setCorrectAnswer("A");
            list_question.add(question);
             */

            for (DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.child("questions").getChildren())
            {
                Question question=new Question();
                question.setQuestion(ds.child("question").getValue().toString());
                question.setAnswerA(ds.child("A").getValue().toString());
                question.setAnswerB(ds.child("B").getValue().toString());
                question.setAnswerC(ds.child("C").getValue().toString());
                question.setAnswerD(ds.child("D").getValue().toString());
                question.setCorrectAnswer(ds.child("sol").getValue().toString());
                list_question.add(question);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    currentQuestion = list_question.get(index);
```

What is missing in my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addValueEventListener` is asynchronous and returns immediately.  Your code goes on to execute `list_question.get(index)`, but `list_question` is still empty.  The listener you provided will not get invoked until some time later, after the database query is complete.  There is no guarantee how long it will take.

If you want to use the results of a query, you must wait until the asynchronous database operation is complete.  This means that you can only use the results inside the listener callback itself.

Answer (score 0):

This methods to retrieve data is asynchronous. Which means that this isn't executed in the chronogical order.
Try to use the debug mode and you will see by yourself that it executes the inside of the listener after executing the rest of the code.
Put the 
currentQuestion= list_question.get(index)
Inside the listener, just after the line where you add your question and you will see that it works.

Answer (score 0):

It is just that you are trying to access the list before it is getting filled.

You can check for the size of the list by putting an if.

```
if(list_question.size() > 0)
  currentQuestion = list_question.get(index);
```

Also make sure that you are doing this logic once a data change event happened.

Hope this helps.

Happy coding :)